# How to give rounded stroke on two different paths in Ai?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, path, corners

I am trying to create an icon in Ai. But the problem I am facing is...

[image]

I want to give a rounded stroke.
Any idea how would I achieve this?

Comment: ...you have to *draw* it. Or expand strokes to shapes.

Comment: @Scott I cannot expand because expanding makes strokes into fill. By doing that my style guide will change. Can you please show me the "Draw" method? Thank You

Comment: You grab the pen tool and create a shape that lays on top of the strokes and makes things appear curved/rounded. There are only 2 solutions - 1) You expand or 2) you create a new object on top that causes the desired appearance. You **can't** do what you want with only 2 stroked paths.

Comment: Alright, Thank You @Scott & Billy Kerr!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily round the corners if you want to keep the lines as open paths with a stroke. There is no way to round a stroke on separate paths where two paths are touching. No such functionality exists. However, it's easy to do this on a closed path which is filled.

1. Select the stroked paths and do *Object > Expand* - this will convert the strokes to shapes with a fill.
2. Open the PathFinder and hit the Unite button. This is a boolean operation to unite the separate pieces
3. Select one of the Live Corner Widgets, and click and drag it.

[image]

It would be possible to retain the paths as strokes, but then you would have to draw a filled shape on top manually to make a piece that gives the illusion of a curved join. Any time you change the strokes, you'd need to manually edit this covering piece.

[image]